# I don't understand why the second version of the snippet compiles. AFAIK it shouldn't, because of §10.3/2

Tags: c++, c++11, overriding, language-lawyer, virtual-functions

This code doesn't compile because of §10.3/2, i.e., virtual function `A::f` has more than one final overrider in `D`.

```
#include <iostream>

class A { public: virtual void f(){ std::cout << "A::f" << '\n'; } };
class B : public virtual A { public: void f(){ std::cout << "B::f" << '\n'; } };
class C : public virtual A { public: void f(){ std::cout << "C::f" << '\n'; } };
class D : public B, public C { };

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.f();
}
```

But contrary to my expectations this code compiles. Given that §10.3/2 contains this sentence, `For convenience we say that any virtual function overrides itself`, it seems to me we have here the same problem mentioned above, i.e., the virtual function `A::f` has more than one final overrider in `D`, that is, `A::f` and `C::f`. As a matter of fact the call `d.f()` invokes `C::f`. Why is that?

```
#include <iostream>

class A { public: virtual void f(){ std::cout << "A::f" << '\n'; } };
class B : public virtual A {};
class C : public virtual A { public: void f(){ std::cout << "C::f" << '\n'; } };
class D : public B, public C { };

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.f();
}
```

Comment: g++ 4.8.1 : "error: request for member ‘f’ is ambiguous"

Comment: @Kiroxas For me it compiles both in clang and g++. (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f07e74ea8a5a752f)

Comment: I assume you understand why it should work, you are just curious about the language in the standard and how it could be interpreted to mean what it should mean?

Comment: @Yakk Not exactly. From what I'm reading in §10.3/2 this code shouldn't compile, as explained above.

Comment: what about the comment in the standard about your example :  // OK: A::f and C::f are the ﬁnal overriders for the B and C subobjects, respectively

Comment: @Kiroxas It was the comment that made me investigate this in more detail. Also, anything said in an example is not considered normative.

Comment: @Cubbi To be honest I didn't understand the answer in the alluded question and it also doesn't say anything about the phrase `For convenience we say that any virtual function overrides itself` in §10.3/2, which an important point of my argument.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil I believe the answer there explains the intent in sufficient detail. In the standard, the intent is demonstrated through the examples: an interpretation of the wording that renders the examples ill-formed is obviously not the expected interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the notion of *final overrider* applies to a particular object, not to a class:

> A virtual member function `C::vf` of a class **object** `S` is a
>   *final overrider* unless the most derived class (1.8) of which S is a base class **subobject** (if any) declares or inherits another member
>   function that overrides `vf`. In a derived class, if a virtual member
>   function of a base class **subobject** has more than one final
>   overrider the program is ill-formed.

Bold text is mine.

The example in the standard doesn't use virtual inheritance. There are two `A` subobjects within `D` - let's call them `A1` and `A2`. `A::f` is a final overrider for `A::f` in `A1` and `B`. `C::f` is a final overrider in `C` (`A2` doesn't have a final overrider). The definition of `D` is well-formed because there is no single base class subobject for which `A::f` would have more than one final overrider in `D`.

In your example, with virtual inheritance, there is only one `A` object, which is a base class subobject of both `B` and `C`. `A::f` is **not** a final overrider in `B`, because the most derived class of which `B` is a base class subobject (namely, `D`) inherits another member function that overrides `A::f` (namely, `C::f`).

So, once again, there is no single base class subobject for which `A::f` would have more than one final overrider in `D`. `C::f` is a final overrider for `A::f` in `C` and `D` objects; `A` and `B` objects don't have a final overrider.

And indeed, [this code](http://ideone.com/hiFzhU) calls `C::f`:

```
// Setup the same as in the OP's example:
D d;
B* pB = &d;
pB->f();  // calls C::f, not A::f
```